# Can I set file name in blob data when I upload data to server using html5?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I use `event.clipboardData` to get image from clipboard, and then upload it server, code:

```
var items = e.clipboardData.items;
for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++)
{
    if(items[i].type.indexOf("image")!=-1)
    {
        var blob=items[i].getAsFile();
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("ImageFileField",blob);
        _post2("url...",data);
    }
}
```

NOTE: `_post2()` is a function using `XMLHttpRequest` to do upload works.

Above code work fine, the image from clipboard can upload to my server directly.

BUT I found a problem, the filename of image upload to server is fixed as "blob", can I modify the filename before upload to server?

This is the upload data detail:

**Request Payload**

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryW0NQVOkdrfkYGWV3
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%%File.48257279001171c9.2c36671da7f1b6c9482575de002e1f14.$Body.0.3D8"; filename=**"blob"**
>
> Content-Type: image/png
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryW0NQVOkdrfkYGWV3--

Answer (score 70):

According to [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append), you should be able to add a filename parameter to your `data.append()` call as follows:

```
data.append("ImageFileField", blob, "imageFilename.png");
```

Comment: works well for my case

Answer (score 9):

i faced same problem that during upload, file name not a assign to multipart with blob object but after a lots of google and RND . i find simple and best approach for this problem.

```
 let file = event.target.files[0];
 this.fileName = file.name;   // Like : abc.jpeg

 this.croppedImage = file  //blob object after cropping
 const formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('file',this.croppedImageSend,this.fileName);
 this.http.post(url, formData, headersOptions)
```

Comment: superb, easy and straight forward answer.

Answer (score 6):

if you want to modify the filename in the blob itself, just add a key called "name"

```
blob.name = "imageFilename.png"
```

After that your JS functions should be able to pick it up. I'm using jQuery File Upload and this works with it.

Comment: blob.name = "imageFileName.png" and blob.filename = "imageFileName.png" did not work for me.

Comment: Same. @NewfrontSolutions Have you found a solution please?

Comment: Yes, I upvoted one of the other answers that worked for me.  data.append("ImageFileField", blob, "imageFilename.png"); is what worked for me.

Comment: @NewfrontSolutions it said that it only work in FF and Chrome, ... did it support all your customer? --- Rechecked official website, and it seem to be ok ---- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: I wish this worked. How is it 2023 and I can't give a blob a custom name (even with `File([blob], 'custom_name.pdf', { type: 'application/pdf' })`
When attempting `blob.name` I'm seeing: Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a read-only property.